# picking same name item from another array

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array named array-variable with 10 values, and array array of images having 10 values.

on calling `rvalue()` function 3 values are selected randomly to array[],

I want to store tempimages[] values as tempimage[0] should be array[0] value jpeg from ArrayOfImages[].

ie, if array[0] is 3, tempimages[0] should be 3.jpeg.

How, do I achieve it?

```js
function rvalue() 
 {
  var array = [];
  var tempimages = [];
  var arrayVariable = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5','6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
  
  var ArrayOfImages = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg' ,'5.jpg','6.jpg', '7.jpg', '8.jpg', '9.jpg' ,'10.jpg'];
  
  arrayLength = arrayVariable.length;

  ptags = document.getElementsByName("values");
  for (i = 0; i < ptags.length; i++) {
    ptags[i].textContent = arrayVariable[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLength)];
    
    array.push(ptags[i].textContent);
    
 tempimages.push(ptags[i].textContent);// 
  }
  console.log(array);
  console.log(tempimages);
}
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<body onload="rvalue()">

<div id="container">
            
                <p name="values"></p></div>
                <p name="values"></p></div>
                <p name="values"></p></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using two different arrays? Can't you just pick 3 random items from the array with the file names?

Comment: yes, seperate array picking is preffered.

Comment: I agree fully with Thijs: separate array picking is not how to do it. Combine elements with objects. That is what objects are for.

Comment: The value of `ArrayOfImages` can always be found by looking for the random value from `arrayVariable` with a `.<extension>` added to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look, is this solving your problem?

```js
function rvalue() {
  const array = [];
  const tempimages = [];
  const arrayVariable = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5','6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
  const ArrayOfImages = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg' ,'5.jpg','6.jpg', '7.jpg', '8.jpg', '9.jpg' ,'10.jpg'];
  
  arrayLength = arrayVariable.length;

  ptags = document.getElementsByName("values");
  for (i = 0; i < ptags.length; i++) {
    ptags[i].textContent = arrayVariable[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLength)];
    array.push(ptags[i].textContent);
   tempimages.push(`${ptags[i].textContent}.jpeg`);
  }
  console.log(array);
  console.log(tempimages);
}
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<body onload="rvalue()">

<div id="container">  
    <p name="values"></p></div>
    <p name="values"></p></div>
    <p name="values"></p></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The array uses `.jpg`, your `tempimages.push` line uses `.jpeg`. This is one of the reasons why this approach is error prone.

Comment: yeah it worked and selection using this tempimages.push method. thanks by the way

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
 for (i = 0; i < ptags.length; i++) {
  ptags[i].textContent = arrayVariable[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLength)]; 
  array.push(ptags[i].textContent);
  let tempArray = ArrayOfImages.slice();
  let temp =   tempArray.filter((val) => val.indexOf(ptags[i].textContent) > -1)
  tempimages.push(temp[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of that can be summarized in 2 lines:

```js
function rvalue() {
  var ArrayOfImages = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '7.jpg', '8.jpg', '9.jpg', '10.jpg'];
  var tempimages = [...document.getElementsByName("values")].map((p) => {
    return p.textContent = ArrayOfImages
      .splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * ArrayOfImages.length), 1).pop();
  });
  
  console.log(tempimages);
}
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<body onload="rvalue()">
  <div id="container">
    <p name="values"></p>
    <p name="values"></p>
    <p name="values"></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Im mutating ArrayOfImages just to guarantee non duplicated result, that's defined in the function scope so its fine. Im picking as many values as the p tags like in the OP snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better design if you would store the combination of an identifier (the content of an `arrayVariable` element) with the corresponding image (the content of an `ArrayOfImages`) in one object, and store those in one array, instead of two. This makes association of different things a piece of cake.

Here is how that would look:

```js
function rvalue() {
    const images = [
        { id: 'BX', img: 'box.jpg' },
        { id: 'TB', img: 'table.jpg' },
        { id: 'LP', img: 'lamp.jpg' },
        { id: 'CP', img: 'cup.jpg' },
        { id: 'PN', img: 'pan.jpg' },
        { id: 'KT', img: 'kettle.jpg' },
        { id: 'CH', img: 'chair.jpg' },
        { id: 'SF', img: 'sofa.jpg' },
        { id: 'TV', img: 'tv.jpg' },
        { id: 'BK', img: 'book.jpg' }
    ];
    const picks = [];
    ptags = document.getElementsByName("values");
    for (let i = 0; i < ptags.length; i++) {
        const pick = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
        ptags[i].textContent = pick.id; // Get the property you want to display
        picks.push(pick); // Store the object(!) which has both properties
    }
    console.log(picks);
}
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<body onload="rvalue()">

<div id="container">
    <span name="values"></span>&nbsp;
    <span name="values"></span>&nbsp;
    <span name="values"></span>&nbsp;
</div>
</body>
```